# How can I check how many `EXPECT_*` calls failed in one test

Tags: c++, googletest

I have an integration test that is something like:

```
TEST(foo, test_many_foos) {
   foo_builder sut;
   sut.set_some_params();

   sut.run();

   for (const auto foo : sut) {
      EXPECT_TRUE(some_check(foo));
   }


   // TODO: Print a summary of how many EXPECT_TRUEs failed

}
```

Is there a way that I can print out a summary of the results of all of the `EXPECT` calls at the end of the test?

Comment: Isn't it stopping after first fail? Nwm, it is `ASSERT_* ` family of macros that abort tests early. Actually according to docs each expect call will add new failure message when condition is false.

Comment: EXPECT allows the test to continue rather than stopping it in its tracks. In my case I am generating around 200,000 `foo`s and about ~50 of them fail. It's too many to count easily by just looking at them by eye. I would like a message at the end saying "X EXPECT failures" or something like that

Answer (score 4):

You could enhance Google Test using a [custom event listener](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#extending-google-test-by-handling-test-events). You can define your own listener class and have it track the number of times an `EXPECT_*()` call fails per test:

```
class ExpectListener : public ::testing::EmptyTestEventListener {
    int nFailures;

    // Called before a test starts.
    virtual void OnTestStart(const ::testing::TestInfo& test_info) {
        nFailures = 0;

        printf("*** Test %s.%s starting.\n",
               test_info.test_case_name(),
               test_info.name());
    }

    // Called after a failed assertion or a SUCCEED() invocation.
    virtual void OnTestPartResult(const ::testing::TestPartResult& test_part_result) {
        if (test_part_result.nonfatally_failed()) {nFailures++;}

        printf("%s in %s:%d\n%s\n",
               test_part_result.failed() ? "*** Failure" : "Success",
               test_part_result.file_name(),
               test_part_result.line_number(),
               test_part_result.summary());
    }

    // Called after a test ends.
    virtual void OnTestEnd(const ::testing::TestInfo& test_info) {
        printf("*** Test %s.%s ending with %d failures.\n",
               test_info.test_case_name(),
               test_info.name(),
               nFailures);
    }
};
```

Now just replace Google Test's default listener with this custom listener:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    ::testing::TestEventListeners& listeners = ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
    delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());
    listeners.Append(new ExpectListener);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

You only need to set this up once (in `main()`); all tests will then track the number of non-fatal failures they've experienced. Of course, you can further customize this listener if you want to tweak the test messages or track more information.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I came up with (that I'm not entirely happy with) is to do the following:

```
class stream_counter
{
public:
    explicit stream_counter(int *val) : val_(val) {}
    void                         increment_count() const { ++*val_; }

private:
    int *val_;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const stream_counter &sc)
{
    sc.increment_count();
    return os;
}

TEST(foo, test_many_foos) {
   foo_builder sut;
   sut.set_some_params();

   sut.run();

   int n_failures = 0;

   for (const auto foo : sut) {
      EXPECT_TRUE(some_check(foo)) << stream_counter{&n_failures};
   }

   if(n_failures > 0) {
      std::cout << "There were " << n_failures << " failures" << std::endl;
   }

}
```

This abuses the `operator <<` behaviour iof `EXPECT_*` which allow printing a message to the error stream if the check fails. `stream_counter` just wraps an integer and increments it if the object is streamed to a `std::ostream`

Not the cleanest solution, but it does what I want.

Comment: You could eliminate that extra class with a lambda: https://gist.github.com/LegalizeAdulthood/179f4ff9b1bc48e380478d1e0138ae4a

Answer (score 0):

```
TEST(foo, test_many_foos) {
   foo_builder sut;
   sut.set_some_params();

   sut.run();

   auto n_failures = 0;
   for (const auto foo : sut) {
      auto const result = some_check(foo);
      EXPECT_TRUE(result);
      if (!result) ++n_failures;
   }

   if(n_failures > 0) {
      std::cout << "There were " << n_failures << " failures" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

This, however, means that EXPECT_TRUE() will print something about "result" rather than "some_check(foo)".